# How to write a task which depends on the built-in `dependencies` task?

Tags: gradle, dependencies, task

Gradle has a `dependencies` task which can output the dependencies as tree.

I want to write a gradle task which depends on it. I tried:

```
task hello(dependsOn: 'dependencies') << {
    println("Hello")
}

task hello() << {
    tasks.dependencies.execute()
    println("Hello")
}
```

But neither works, it will report the `dependencies` is not found.

And when I use `tasks.each({println it})`, the output doesn't have `dependencies` task, but `gradle tasks --all` have that.

What is the correct way to depend on `dependencies`?

Comment: What does not work? The dependencies list is printed out to console. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Have you solved the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Still don't get it, the following script works perfectly fine:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

task hello(dependsOn: 'dependencies') << {
    println("Hello")
}

task hello2() << {
    tasks.dependencies.execute()
    println("Hello")
}
```

Dependency tree is printed to console.